# Increasing Range of Night Vision Cameras

Tags: lighting, security

Will replacing a regular fluorescent floodlight with and infrared floodlight increase the clarity/range of my night vision cameras? If not, are there other methods to increase clarity/range of my night vision cameras, without replacing said cameras?

Found the following bulb:

http://www.elightbulbs.com/General-600530-TSG-PAR38-IR-175W-E27-240V-RED-PAR38-Reflector-Flood-Spot-Light-Bulb&source=GoogleBaseCSE?gclid=CNf6svCVw8gCFYgYHwodjtgHiQ

Says it's a "Heat Lamp," which sortof threw me. Should that qualification deter me from procuring it? Incandescent bulbs produce heat, what's the difference with infrared bulbs? Isn't that just the tinting of the light itself?

Comment: @Kris kudos for the clarity bit. knew when i wrote that, that it likely wouldn't improve clarity. just updated the question with more info, care to clarify? i'd appreciate the input, especially from a credible source ...

Comment: Maybe a stupid question (as I don't see you mention this exactly), but is the camera an IR camera or just a low light camera? The only way a heat bulb would work is if the camera is an IR receiving camera ... then things would probably show up like nobody's business.

Comment: What you have there is a infrared heat lamp, but what you're trying to accomplish uses infrared light-emitting diodes. Most decent IP cams come with built in infrared LEDs.

Comment: Is this for a 35mm camera or rifle scope?

Comment: The heat lamp will brighten the objects and give you a greater field of view. And it won't fry your night vision apparatus.

Comment: heres a link   https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Infrared+-+Heat+Lamp+

Comment: Rather than an expensive to use (175w!!) and super hot bulb, use an LED bulb like this http://www.ledtronics.com/Products/product_new.aspx?id=R30-123-851-120AS

Comment: @culturalanomoly- One of my first modifications was adapting a 35mm camera lens (with a manual focus) so it replaced the lens from a cheap Harbor Freight night vision scope. It actually worked!

Comment: got the spotlight in, after proper adjustments, night turned to day.

Comment: @ojait that's my next task, upgrading the cams ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Night vision, the type most sold to the public, relies on some low level lighting to enhance and produce objects. Infra red light does this or any light with a red output (or any red colored lens in front of a standard bulb). The heat lamp spot bulb will allow you to view objects in a larger area(or field of view) and see them brighter, but unless your camera or scope has a lens that can focus you will not be able to see any further than what the lens is set at.